# Setting the maximum value of a UISlider causing strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am having a really weird issue trying to use a UISlider, when I change the maximumValue of the slider to > 1.0, I get this weird duplicate slider appearing on my view. Please help :)

Heres what it looks like when slider.maximumValue = 10.0;
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/827/kf12.png

Heres what it looks like when slider.maximumValue = 1.0;
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/197/bcvf.png

Is there some behaviour of a UISlider I am missing? Here is my code for configuring the slider...

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize viewSize = self.contentSubview.bounds.size;

    self.timeSlider.frame = CGRectMake(viewSize.width / 2 - 80,
                                       viewSize.height / 2 - 12,
                                       viewSize.width / 2,
                                       24);

    -(void)configureSubviews
    {
        [super configureSubviews];

        self.timeSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.timeSlider.continuous = YES;
        self.timeSlider.minimumValue = 0;
        self.timeSlider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
        [self.timeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(timeValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.contentSubview addSubview:self.timeSlider];

    }

    -(void)timeValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider
    {
        self.timeValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d min", (int)floorf(slider.value)];
        [self layoutSubviews];
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a difference in the two images.

Comment: make sure you invoke configureSubviews only one time

Comment: see first image top left it is show slider drag button it is not in second image. i think this is different  @rmaddy

Comment: OK, I see it now in the very top left there is half of a thumb showing.

Comment: Yeah sorry I could have pointed that out better, its a tiny slider button in top left corner, I still can't figure out how it ended up there.. This view is also just a basic subclass of UIView

Comment: You should not call layoutSubviews method directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**layoutSubviews**
Lays out subviews.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

**Discussion**

The default implementation of this method does nothing on iOS 5.1 and earlier. Otherwise, the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.

Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise layout of their subviews. You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want. You can use your implementation to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

**You should not call this method directly**. If you want to force a layout update, call the **setNeedsLayout** method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the **layoutIfNeeded** method.

Referance by [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews)

Comment: Alright. I was not aware that I shouldn't call layoutSubviews directly. I will fix it like you suggested. Thanks!!